# Is "posit Pluto not a planet" a valid rendering of "posit that Pluto is not a planet"?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, transitive-verbs

The fragment "posit Pluto not a planet" is particularly awkward, but would "posit tomato a fruit" or "posit tomatoes as fruits" be any better as a rendering of "posit that tomatoes are fruits"?

Comment: Why, did Peter Piper posit Pluto not a planet?  And after Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled pepper? So where's the peck of pickled pepper Peter piper picked and the planet Pluto Peter Piper posited wasn't?

Comment: Typically, we posit *positive* things (the morphology isn't a coincidence, there). Of course, just as we can *assert* a negative (*Dan asserted he never indulged in pedantry*), though we would technically be *denying*, we can *posit* a negative. It's just not as common.